# Can I put a clock on both taskbars

Tags: windows-10, clock

I'm a gamer.
I have 2 monitors.
The clock's always on the game window, so I never know what time it is.
Is there a way to put the clock on the task bar of the other screen too?
I'm running windows 10 btw.

Comment: The clock is only displayed on the primary monitor.  Simplest solution would be to change which monitor is your primary monitor then place the application in Window mode and change which monitor it is displayed on.  Or just third-party software to display the time, ( or get a clock )

Comment: Clock on each taskbar is coming with the Windows 10 Anniversary Update later in 2016

Comment: It may be worthwhile un marking this as a duplicate - It is now separate to the linked question (Windows 8) as they now have to separate answers